# How to share OpenVPN connection on Big Sur?

Tags: macos, network, vpn, internet-sharing

The NordVPN client creates a connection entry of its OpenVPN connection, so that it can be shared with all devices connecting via my computer. I have another OpenVPN connection, which is not part of NordVPN, which I connect to using other clients. But none of those clients create a connection entry in Network and Sharing Settings, so I can't share it. How do I add such an entry into the connections list for sharing?

[image: Connection Sharing]